# Cannot understand how Bayes rule was applied in this example

Tags: probability

I cannot understand how Bayes rule was applied here (from video lecture):
[image]

should not it be like:
$$\frac{p(f,e,m|a) * p(a)}{P(f,e,m)}$$ ???

Comment: Please edit the title of your Question to correct the spelling of "Bayes rule".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be some steps skipped.

$$P(a|f,e,m)=\frac{P(a,f,e,m)}{P(f,e,m)}=\frac{P(f,a|e,m)P(e,m)}{P(f,e,m)}.$$

Now just expand the denominator:

$$P(f,e,m)=\sum_a P(f,e,m,a)=\sum_a P(f,a|e,m)P(e,m).$$

And the $P(e,m)$ terms will cancel in numerator and denominator.